# Extracting href from attribute with BeatifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I use this method

```
allcity = dom.body.findAll(attrs={'id' : re.compile("\d{1,2}")})
```

to return a list like this:

```
[<a onmousedown="return c({'fm':'as','F':'77B717EA','F1':'9D73F1E4','F2':'4CA6DE6B','F3':'54E5243F','T':'1279189248','title':this.innerHTML,'url':this.href,'p1':1,'y':'B2D76EFF'})" href="http://www.ylyd.com/showurl.asp?id=6182" target="_blank"><font size="3">掳虏驴碌路驴碌脴虏煤脨脜脧垄脥酶 隆煤 脢脦脝路脦露脕卢陆脫</font></a>, 
<a href="http://cache.baidu.com/c?m=9f65cb4a8c8507ed4fece763105392230e54f728629c86027fa3c215cc791a1b1a23a4fb7935107380843e7000db120afdf14076340920a3de95c81cd2ace52f38fb5023716c914b19c46ea8dc4755d650e34d99aa0ee6cae74596b9a1d6c85523dd58716df7f49c5b7003c065e76445&amp;p=8b2a9403c0934eaf5abfc8385864&amp;user=baidu" target="_blank" class="m">掳脵露脠驴矛脮脮</a>]
```

How do I extract this href?

```
http://www.ylyd.com/showurl.asp?id=6182
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Your question looks broken. I think `"a href="#####" /a"` was meant to look something like `<a href="####"></a>`, but I'm not sure. Also, use four spaces of indent to depict code.

Comment: Thanks But Stackoverflow can not write HTML code

Comment: Your call to findAll has returned two results - two anchor tags. You have asked to extract one of the href attributes from these tags. Why the first one and not the second one? (What filtering did you want?)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
for a in dom.body.findAll(attrs={'id' : re.compile("\d{1,2}")}, href=True):
   a['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there's no real need to use `regex`, it can be simply as calling `<a>` tag and then `['href']` attribute like so:

```py
get_me_url = soup.a['href'] # http://www.ylyd.com/showurl.asp?id=6182
# cached URL
get_me_cached_url = soup.find('a', class_='m')['href']
```

You can always use `prettify()` method to better see the HTML code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''
[
<a href="http://www.ylyd.com/showurl.asp?id=6182" onmousedown="return c({'fm':'as','F':'77B717EA','F1':'9D73F1E4','F2':'4CA6DE6B','F3':'54E5243F','T':'1279189248','title':this.innerHTML,'url':this.href,'p1':1,'y':'B2D76EFF'})" target="_blank">
 <font size="3">
  掳虏驴碌路驴碌脴虏煤脨脜脧垄脥酶 隆煤 脢脦脝路脦露脕卢陆脫
 </font>
</a>
,
<a class="m" href="http://cache.baidu.com/c?m=9f65cb4a8c8507ed4fece763105392230e54f728629c86027fa3c215cc791a1b1a23a4fb7935107380843e7000db120afdf14076340920a3de95c81cd2ace52f38fb5023716c914b19c46ea8dc4755d650e34d99aa0ee6cae74596b9a1d6c85523dd58716df7f49c5b7003c065e76445&amp;p=8b2a9403c0934eaf5abfc8385864&amp;user=baidu" target="_blank">
 掳脵露脠驴矛脮脮
</a>
]
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
href = soup.a['href']
cache_href = soup.find('a', class_='m')['href']
print(f'{href}\n{cache_href}')

# output:
'''
http://www.ylyd.com/showurl.asp?id=6182
http://cache.baidu.com/c?m=9f65cb4a8c8507ed4fece763105392230e54f728629c86027fa3c215cc791a1b1a23a4fb7935107380843e7000db120afdf14076340920a3de95c81cd2ace52f38fb5023716c914b19c46ea8dc4755d650e34d99aa0ee6cae74596b9a1d6c85523dd58716df7f49c5b7003c065e76445&p=8b2a9403c0934eaf5abfc8385864&user=baidu
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Baidu Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/baidu-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Essentially, the main difference in this example is that you don't have to figure out how to grab certain elements since it's already done for the end-user with a `JSON` output.

Code to grab `href`/`cached href` from first page results:

```py
from serpapi import BaiduSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "baidu",
  "q": "ylyd"
}

search = BaiduSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  # try/expect used since sometimes there's no link/cached link
  try:
    link = result['link']
  except:
    link = None
  try:
    cached_link = result['cached_page_link']
  except:
    cached_link = None
  print(f'{link}\n{cached_link}\n')

# Part of the output:
'''
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=7VlSB5iaA1_llQKA3-0eiE8O9sXe4IoZzn0RogiBMCnJHcgoDDYxz2KimQcSDoxK
http://cache.baiducontent.com/c?m=LU3QMzVa1VhvBXthaoh17aUpq4KUpU8MCL3t1k8LqlKPUU9qqZgQInMNxAPNWQDY6pkr-tWwNiQ2O8xfItH5gtqxpmjXRj0m2vEHkxLmsCu&p=882a9646d5891ffc57efc63e57519d&newp=926a8416d9c10ef208e2977d0e4dcd231610db2151d6d5106b82c825d7331b001c3bbfb423291505d3c77e6305a54d5ceaf13673330923a3dda5c91d9fb4c57479c77a&s=c81e728d9d4c2f63&user=baidu&fm=sc&query=ylyd&qid=e42a54720006d857&p1=1
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.